# Using AND in Switch Expression in SSRS 2008 ( no nested IIF statement please)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my ssrs Chart ihave two groupings category and series grouping and i have four block of chart, in each block i have different color:

My question is how to say that in switch statement:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Code.Value="somthing" and Fields!Grp.Value="ThisRelateToSomthing", "Red",
Fields!Code.Value="somthingElse" and Fields!Grp.Value="ThisRelateToSomthingElse", "Blue")
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried that statement? It looks fine to me. If so, what issues did you run into?

Comment: it did worked, i just didn't have the right date to test it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

For the `SWITCH` statement, the first argument can be any boolean expression, so it's perfectly fine to use multiple statements linked by `and`/`or` as long as `true` or `false` is returned.

If the expression evaluates to `true`, it will return the associated constant in the second argument, if not it will move on to the next statement until one evaluates to `true` or there are no more to check.

So the `SWITCH` statement in your question looks fine as it is. You should just give it a try and see if it works.